# cant get libsensors to work properly

Tags: c, linux

here is my code concerning libsensors.
libraries:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sensors/sensors.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
```

code concerning libsensors:

```
char sd[16384]="^\0",bf[1];
char buf2[8192]="^\0";


sensors_chip_name const* scn;
int c=0;
int t4=1;
while((scn=sensors_get_detected_chips(0,&c))!=0)
{
        sensors_feature const *fea;
        int f=0;
        strcat(sd,scn->prefix);
        printf("%s",scn->prefix);
        strcat(sd,":");
        strcat(sd,scn->path);
        strcat(sd,"(");
        while((fea=sensors_get_features(scn,&f))!=0)
        {

                strcat(sd,fea->name);
                strcat(sd,"(");
                sensors_subfeature const *sb;
                int s=0;
                while((sb=sensors_get_all_subfeatures(scn,fea,&s))!=0)
                {
                        t4++;
                        strcat(sd,sb->name);
                        strcat(sd,",");
                        int t3=-1;
                        int i=0;
                        char t8[sizeof(sb->number)];
                        memcpy(&t8,&(sb->number),sizeof(sb->number));
                        strcat(sd,t8);
                        strcat(sd,"!");
                }
                strcat(sd,")");
        }
        strcat(sd,")");

}
```

so when I try to print anything nothing happens. char array called `sd` returns empty. it simply seems that there are no sensors to be read.

when I run `sensors` from terminal it works perfectly fine. I see a couple of cores and chips temps.

I implemented this code from some post on here and to be frank I don't totally understand it.

Comment: "nothing happens" is a very coarse error description. Be more specific and use a debugger to step your code.

Comment: @Olaf I mean to say that functions return empty I guess. buffers are not with data without any visible errors, that is why I am posting here.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `"^\0"` in the initializer for the char buffers?   The usual initializer is `{'\0'}` which sets all the character contents of the buffer to 0x00.

Comment: is `scn->prefix` supposed to be a NUL terminated string?  is `scn->path` supposed to be a NUL terminated string?

Comment: `fea` is a pointer, so it should never be `0`, however; it might be `NULL`

Comment: when indenting code, do not use tabs, because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.   Always use spaces.

Comment: Im using ubuntu linux 14.04.  Where would I find the documentation for that libsensors?

Comment: @user3629249 libsensors is a library which comes with lm-sensors. http://linux.die.net/man/3/libsensors I will check your suggestions and work with them thank you very much for the pointers that you have given.

Comment: The variable `t4` gets set and gets incremented but never used.

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing the call to: `sensors_init()`

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for your help, I was not able to see the elephant in the room it seems if you can post it here I can mark that as the solution :). about t4, it is used later on. thank you again for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting [@user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249) comment as a community answer.*

---

It it required to first call `sensors_init()` otherwise the chips list will be empty.

This function expects a `sensors` configuration file as argument, or `NULL` to use the default one.

Also, you can find an usage example in this related question: [Has anyone been able to use libsensors properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565176/2291710)